# WPF + Windows Forms, open a second Form as child of MainWindow from the first Form

Tags: c#, wpf, forms

Probably I will not make myself clear in the title, change it if necessary. Now I step to explanation:

I have a program done in WPF (cause graphics). The MainWindow open a first Form with a button, the Form1 do some stuff, changing the UI of the MainWindow and when it is done should open a Form2 that it should also do some things changing the UI of the MainWindow, but I can't open the Form2 through Form1.

Here's some code:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
internal static MainWindow main; //It allows me to put the Form1 in the same context in order to change the UI
private void start_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Form1 frm = new Form1(this);
     frm.Show();
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
//function that allow me to communicate with the MainWindow
private MainWindow main1 = null;

public Form1(MainWindow callingForm)
{
     main1 = callingForm as MainWindow;
     InitializeComponent();
}

//Load function
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //do some stuff changing MainWindow UI
     Form2 frm = new Form2(main1); //no compilation error
     frm.Show();
}
```

Now, the Form2 does not open. I also tried to do it calling a void that is in the MainWindow with the Form1 but nothing. What I have to do? NOTE WELL: need to change the UI of the main window also with the Form2 and I need that Form2 is opened only at the end of the Form1 calculations.

Comment: What namespace is `Form`? Looks like that's for Winforms?

Comment: Namespace "Application__WPF" @lll

Comment: Can you try wrapping your function call for `Form2` in a `Dispatcher`? Such as `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`

Comment: With a Dispatcher does not work @lll

Answer (score 0):

```
    public Form1(MainWindow callingForm)
    {
        main1 = callingForm as MainWindow;
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }
```

Comment: This crashes the entire Form1, it loads automatically

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open a window from the MainWindow, I would recommend you to use `events` to instanciate the window.

It is a bit weird from a structure standpoint to a child view to say to his parent: "Hey, I want YOU to open this form" - yet it is the Form1 that creates and shows it.

I would do something like this:

**MainWindow:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void start_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        frm.MyEvent += Form1EventMethod;
        frm.Show();
    }

    private void Form1EventMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // You can add here what you need to change in the MainWindow.

        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.Show();
    }
}
```

**Form1:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Window
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void show_form_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(MyEvent != null)
            MyEvent(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Also this way, you may subscribe more than just the MainWindow if you want to do something when this event is raised. Also, you may pass differents parameters to your subscribers. Your views will be seperated and not dependant on one and another.

Comment: Nice try, good explanation but not working :( the Form2 does not show

Answer (score 0):

I know what you mean, you want to call a window form from a WPF application main window. I've prepared this test Program to help you understand the how to programmatically achieve this.

Consider the following simple program: 
1) takes 2 numbers as user input (using TextBoxes). 
2) displays the result in a customized window form that pops up as response to a calculate button.

When the user press the 'Calculate' button ( not show in this answer), the program adds the 2 number then displays the result in a customized window form (that acts like a dialog box ).

Assuming this is what you're looking for here's the caculateclick method that responds to the user's click :

**In MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
    private void calculateClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {   
            int leftHandSide = System.Int32.Parse(lhsOperand.Text); //user input
            int rightHandSide = System.Int32.Parse(rhsOperand.Text); // lhsOperand and rhsOperand are just references to TextBoxes that takes user input
            string  result_txt=addValues(leftHandSide,rightHandSide).ToString(); // add two numbers that returns the result
           //addValues method is not defined in my answer, it's just a method I use in this example to add 2 values together     

            CustomDialog.show(result_txt); // diplays result in a custom window form
        }

        catch (FormatException exception )
        {
            exception.ToString();

        }
```

**All you need to do is to create a class for the user-defined Form then inside this class define the show static method which main window is going to call from the caculateClick() method seen above** ( I will show you the code just keep reading ). Notice the call to the static **method 'CustomDialog.show(result_txt);'**

CustomDialog is a partial class ( just like the Form1 class you created) displays the result of the addition, in a user-defined form that's going to act like a dialog box. ( I assume you know to design the user interface for the form using the design view in Visual Studio ).

**Here's the code for CustomDialog:**

```
      public partial class CustomDialog : Form // CustomDialog 
         {
           static CustomDialog MsgBox; //used in show method as a reference
            static DialogResult result; //retuned by show method

    public CustomDialog()
             {
              InitializeComponent();
              result = DialogResult.OK; //initialise the result according to the function of the button, here I only use the OK button to close the dialog       }

    public static DialogResult show (string calculationResult) // show static method called by the Main Window  
        {
        MsgBox = new CustomDialog();
        MsgBox.result_text.Text = calculationResult; // result_text is a textbox implemented in the form using design view
        MsgBox.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent; // center dialog in the middle of the parent (WPF application main window)
        MsgBox.ShowDialog(); // displays the dialog
        return result; // returns the result so the button event is handled 
         }
```

We define two fields in the CustomDialog class,
`static CustomDialog MsgBox; static DialogResult result;` the MsgBox object is used in the static method called 'show ( string calculation )' in order to display the dialog box and return the 'result' variavle which is a DialogResult object. ( DialogResult is returned so we can see the result in the TextBox and handle event clicks ).

**Important NOTE:** 
To avoid any errors it's crucial that you maintain the form using the following methods that does some background work and handle button clicks and label clicks on the dialog ( even if your not going to use them, you can just leave them empty). **Also make sure that 'CustomDialog' and the 'MainWindow' for the WPF application is implemented in the SAME namespace**

Consider adding the following methods to your CustomDialog class as good practice in case you face some errors :

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) // the name of this method depends on what you name it when you first create the form
    { 

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       result = DialogResult.OK; // handle result returned by show() method, here I only used an OK button
       MsgBox.Close(); //closes the dialogbox


    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

**Design Notes:** Be careful when you create the form in Design View you must assign the button you dragged into it as an Acceptbutton in the Misc section within the Properties tab in Visual Studio. Also keep in mind that **I refer to MessageBox, Dialogbox and Form as the same entity**. Actually if you carefully examine my code, the 'MsgBox' static variable is a CustomDialog Object.

Sorry for the long post but hope this helps ! if you need screen shots to show you that it works and if it's helpful, let me know.